# django rename image in view

Tags: image-manipulation, django-views

I want to rename an image that is uploaded with a Modelform and I want to do this in the view because the path depends on the user who uploaded it.
So far i have this:

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    form = AddImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_image = form.save(commit=false)
```

But how do I get the image, rename it and save it. (Maybe I will also do some additional proccessing like resizing, etc.)
I'm quite new to python an Django and I have no clue how to manipulate files.

Best Jacques

Answer (score 0):

the `os` module lets you interact with the filesystem, and the data in the all the uploaded files is available in the dict request.FILES.

[Django file upload docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs)

so maybe you would do `request.files.items()[0][1]`